# Python3: How do I append multiple key,value pairs to a dictionary in for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to append key, value pairs to my empty dictionary.

I can succeed with one object but not multiple:

```
a[key] = [value]
```

My code returns error 'TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2' - Is it possible to pass the key, values as variables?

```
dict = {"Avv": 33333, "Animal": 22, "color": 12, "location": 40000000}

a = {}

for key, value in dict.items():
    if key.startswith("A"):
        a.update(key, value)
    else:
        #does something
```

Desired outcome:

```
print(a)
{"Avv": 33333, "Animal": 22}
```

Comment: Why not just use `a[key] = value`?

Comment: Is there any reason to use `update` method? You can update simply like `a[key] = value`.

Comment: I want to create a dictionary that can be further manipulated. `a[key] = value` returns `{'Avv': [33333]} {'Animal': [22]}` rather than `{"Avv": 33333, "Animal": 22}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple one liner

```
a = {k:v for (k,v) in dict.items() if k.startswith("A")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

a = {key: value for key, value in dict.items() if key.startswith("A")}

Also, I would avoid naming your first dictionary `dict`. That's a builtin name in Python, so it could mess up code further down the script. Try something like my_dictionary, or something more descriptive of what it's meant to hold.